# Peculiar output from http.get request?

Tags: node.js, http

I'm trying to make a simple http request that follows a redirect:

```
http.get('http://www.example.com/', function(res){
  var data = [];

  res.on('data', function(chunk){
    data.push(chunk)
  }).on('end', function(){
    var buffer = Buffer.concat(data);
    // console.log(buffer.toString('base64')) //This outputs random string
    console.log(buffer)
 })
})
```

This response I'm getting is:

```
<Buffer 3c 21 44 4f 43 54 59 50 45 20 68 74 6d 6c 3e 0a 3c 68 74 6d 6c 3e 0a 3c 68 65 61 64 3e 0a 20 20 20 20 3c 6d 65 74 61 20 68 74 74 70 2d 65 71 75 69 76 ... >
```

I've also tried to JSON parse this by adding:

```
var parsedData = JSON.parse(data); 
console.log(parsedData)
```

This errors due to the `<` symbol not being processed by the json-parse module.

The `res.statusCode` is outputting `200`.

I'm not sure whether this is an encoding error or if the request has failed to follow the redirect? This doesn't look like hexadecimal encoding.

Has anyone else seen this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening here is you're parsing response data as binary data (Buffer) and pushing the binary data to an array. The binary object you're seeing in the console is actually expected behaviour :)

If you want a JSON response, you need to append the data buffer to a string and then parse it:

```
http.get('http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two', function(res){
    var data = '';

    res.on('data', function(chunk){
        data += chunk;
    }).on('end', function(){
        var json = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(json);
    });
});
```

Now that we've got that out of the way, have a look at [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) — it makes API calls WAY easier than the native HTTP module ;)

Comment: Not a problem! 